# Transfert specific topics from an ROS master to another

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
i was working with two computers using the same ROS master as described at [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) it is working well but the problem is that i want to transfer only some specific topics and not all topics. since the two packages i am using in each computer publish on tf, i have problem while recording the bag file. can someone suggest a better way to do it? what i mean is that i run ROSCORE in each of two machines(computers) and i send the topics that i wanted from a master to another.

PS: i was about to use the foreign_relay package but it seems it is not possible to download it(if someone could give me the link to download it, that would be perfect :D)

Thanks! all help will be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201319/transfert-specific-topics-from-an-ros-master-to-another/) by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-01-20**:
Usually the two tf publishers should not interfere, it's very common to have a huge amount of tf broadcasters. Could you describe a bit more want your issue is with this?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-01-20**:
Note that for tf it is very important that clocks of both machines are in sync so make sure  there is an NTP connection between both comuters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few implementations of Multimaster functionality out there, but none has really reached the status of being "the recommended implementation". Other examples beyond the one @ahendrix mentioned are:

- [ROCON Multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_launch/Tutorials/indigo/Rocon%20Launch%20for%20Multiple%20Masters)
- [topic_proxy](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/topic_proxy) (We use that and it works for us)
- [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie)

If you google for "multimaster ros" you'll also find other material, such as the [Multimaster SIG group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-mm)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on 2015-01-20**:
Thank you for the answer, can you give me a quick explain of how to use the topic_proxy? that would be very helpful to me.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-01-26**:
The README at github has a complete example. Have you tried that?

**Comment by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on 2015-01-26**:
Thanks for the help but i figured out how to deal with it using the foreign relay package, even though it is not the best solution.
Keep it up :)